# HttpWebRequest was cancelled

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I am using ASP.NET to read a Request.InputStream and send a HttpRequest to a page that was sent to me throw a QueryString parameter, I read correctly the Request.InputStream and I make the HttpRequest correctly, but when in my Request.InputStream I find special characters like this "PorsvÃ¤gen" the I get this error:
ystem.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)

My code for getting the Request.InputStream is this:

```
string requestData = (new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)).ReadToEnd();
```

My code for making a HttpRequest and sending it is this:

```
    webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlDestination));
    webRequest.Method = "POST";

    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

    writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);//<-------Here I get the ERROR
    if (writer != null)
    {
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code, because it works, but for special characters it crashes.

Comment: What type of special characters does the code crash / throw an exception for?

Comment: ÃƒÂ¤ this is the characters that made the crash they were in a XML like a 5673 length XML that contained this ÃƒÂ¤ characters, not all of them were special only those 4.

Comment: `The request was aborted` indicates that the [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx) was called on the request at some point. Probably worth posting your input request code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have manage to overcome the error by implementing this:

```
        string requestData = (new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)).ReadToEnd();
        byte[] bytes = Request.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(requestData);

        Stream writer = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

I used Stream to write the `HttpWebRequest` instead of `StreamWriter` and read the `InputStream` in bytes using the `ContentEncoding`